# Android - Drawable has different color in different places

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-resources

I have a drawable resource that has a different shades of black in different places

[image]

Drawable code:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M12,2C6.48,2 2,6.48 2,12s4.48,10 10,10 10,-4.48 10,-10S17.52,2 12,2zM13,17h-2v-6h2v6zM13,9h-2L11,7h2v2z"/>
</vector>
```

How do i change the color of the icon in the cards to be the same as the one in the navigation drawer?

Edit:
It happens even when the nav drawer is closed 
Screenshot when the nav drawer is closed:

[image]

Comment: it should have same color at both the place. bacially what happens when you open your navigation drawer, a shadow or we can say semi transparent layer is inserted between your main fragment and drawer fragment which changes you icon color, so you can remove that shadow

Comment: Your navigation drawer changes it.

Comment: If you use menu in drawer it will be always in this color. You can create own list with own menu items and put it to drawer.

Comment: @mwisnicki But i WANT it to be the way it is in the drawer. How do i change it in the cardview?

Comment: Tint it to the same color or change the color in your svg xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because in your navigation view, your menu elements contains the svg and tint it with the default `colorControlActivated` resource color, so you can change the svg color in your xml file, or tint it anywhere you're using it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the Design Support Library. It may be that the library automatically tints the drawable color to be that shade of gray.

I'd reccomend getting the hex value for that gray and setting `android:fillColor="#FF000000"` to be that value. This way you will have the same gray color everywhere.